# MySQL timing out while indexing

Tags: mysql, indexing, mysql-workbench

I uploaded a 95 million row by 9 column file to a MySQL database on my workstation which has 32 Gb of memory. They're genetic data where the first columns are chromosome number (chr TINYINT) and genomic position (pos BIGINT). I'm trying to create an index in MySQL Workbench 8.0 on chr and pos, but the indexing is taking hours until it times out.

I also tried indexing just on chromosome (which is simply a signed TINYINT from 1 to 22) without success. Is it normal to indexing to hang for hours like that? The Windows task manager says I'm only using 8 Gb of memory.

Comment: Can you share the table structure `SHOW CREATE TABLE table`, MySQL version with `SELECT VERSION()` and the query you run to add the index?

Answer (score 0):

A trick, that worked for me, when I was playing with SQL is - add index before uploading the data.

Right after executing create table statement, add

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> ADD KEY ...
```

And then start your upload.

If your dump has `CREATE TABLE ...` statement, be sure it has also `IF NOT EXISTS` and does not has `DROP TABLE ...`.

I'm not sure about Windows, but for my Ubuntu, that I used as server for MySQL playground, 16Gb RAM were good enough for proccessing 50M+ row tables.